# Insert string between quotation marks using RegEx

Tags: php, regex

I am allowing the user to create `XML` elements with blank attribute values such as this:

```
<crimes id="" total="" />
```

at the same time I am also retrieving an `associative array` from a database to be used to fill up the attributes that the XML specifies. The array will look like this:

```
array(
    theft => 123,
    burglary => 456
)
```

After retrieving the array, I want to use that array to populate the attribute values of the XML which have been passed in. So as an example, the first array element combined with the example XML would look like this:

```
<crimes id="theft" total="123" />
```

Is there a way to use `regular expression` in `PHP` to insert the `array values` between the quotation marks of the `XML attributes`?

Comment: How are you building the xml? You should really be using some sort of xml parser/object like simplexml, then setting attributes is easy.

Comment: Don't use regex for this; use XML or DOM document.

Comment: I will not be able to use DOM or XML because I do now know what the element name will be, nor will I know how many attributes the XML will contain.

Comment: @user3166216 then how would you know where to insert these values by using regexp?

Comment: I will be used the quotation marks of the attributes as like delimiters.

Comment: Will the attribute names Always be "id" and "total" ?

Comment: In some cases the user might specify this form of XML: `<england total="" />`, which uses only the total. But for other cases the attributes of 'id' and 'totals' are used

Comment: You don't need to know names of anything; [DOMNode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php) has a `childNodes` attribute that enumerates all children and an `attributes` attribute that enumerates, er, attributes. Both of these act like regular arrays.

Comment: Trying to modify XML with regular expressions is going to leave you full of sorrow.  Use a proper XML parser tool.

Answer (score 0):

The only time this will work, is if the XML tags you receive are consistent. They need to be the same every time, otherwise there is **no pattern**, and regex is used for matching **patterns**.

If your tags will always have `id` and `total`, then I can write a regex for it. But if they *sometimes* have one or the other, it gets too complicated and you need a parser.

Answer (score 0):

Although (as you've been already told) you should better use SimpleXML or DOM for this, here is a custom RegEx solution you asked for:

```
$list = array(
    "theft" => 123,
    "burglary" => 456
);

$template = '<crimes id="" total="" />';

foreach($list as $key => $value)
{
    $s =  preg_replace('/(id=")(")/', '${1}'.$key.'${2}', $template);
    $s = preg_replace('/(total=")(")/', '${1}'.$value.'${2}', $s);
    echo htmlentities($s)."<br>";
}
```

Here is its output:

```
<crimes id="theft" total="123" />
<crimes id="burglary" total="456" />
```

If "id" or "total" is missing - it just omits it.